# PHP: What's the mathematically efficient way to find a 'subgrid' of a larger grid?

Tags: php, math, performance

i'm trying to find an efficient way to find a subportion of a large grid. Currently I'm looping through rows to define a FROM-TO selection of ids in that row, but this doesn't feel right...

Let's say I have a grid of 200x200 fields (x between 1 and 200, y between 1 and 200). Every field also has it's unique ID, starting at X1,Y1 (fieldid = 1) to X200,Y200 (fieldid = 40000).

I have a subportion of the grid that I need to select from the database (based on XY-ranges or unique id's, where uniqueids are much faster so preferred). The subportion is defined by the upperleft field (again based on XY value or a unique id) and then 16 fields wide and 9 fields high.

**So, how can I efficiently select a subgrid of 144 fields (16x9) of a large grid of 40000 fields (200x200) based on the unique-id or XY-value of the upperleft field in the 16x9 subgrid?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure if I understand the problem you are trying to overcome, some context would probably help... anyway, here goes...

x1 -> x2 = 16 spaces
y1 -> y2 = 9  spaces

x1*y1 = start ID

x2*y2 = end ID

you will have nine ranges (where 'a' is the valid range):

```
x1*y1 < a < (x1*y1)+16
x1*(y1+1) < a < (x1*(y1+1))+16
x1*(y1+2) < a < (x1*(y1+2))+16
....
x1*(y1+8) < a < (x1*(y1+8))+16
```

Comment: You're slightly off, it should be x1*y1<= a, else wise you will only have 15 elements, ie start at 1,1 1<a<16={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}=c,|c|=15.

Also it should be noted that you can solve for x1 and y1 from the start ID, with integer division and the remainder, ie S_Id/200=y1 and S_Id%200=x1.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the [geometry extension in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/spatial-extensions.html) is pretty well optimized. So the most efficient way would be to add a column of type `POINT` to your table holding the position in the matrix.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD COLUMN pos POINT NOT NULL;
```

Then you can select using [the extension's functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/relations-on-geometry-mbr.html) (Example for selecting 16x9 area starting at coordinates 10/10):

```
SET @polygon = GeomFromText('Polygon((10 10, 26 10, 26 19, 10 19, 10 10))');
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE MBRContains(@polygon, pos);
```